# swift UIDatePicker change font, font color, font size etc

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I've been trying to change font in native UIDatePicker in iOS and I did it, but with some unsettled details:

I use extension for UIDatePicker to change font in it's labels:

```
extension UIDatePicker {

func stylizeView(view: UIView? = nil) {
    let view = view ?? self
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
            if let text = label.text {
                print("UIDatePicker :: sylizeLabel :: \(text)\n")

                label.font = UIFont(name: "MyriadPro-Light", size: 17)!
            }
        } else { stylizeView(subview) }
    }
}}
```

So, you can customize font deeply:

```
struct DatePickerStyle {
let tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0xFFFFFF)
let font = UIFont(name: "MyriadPro-Light", size: 17)!
let fontColor = UIColor(hex: 0x000000)
let fontKern: CGFloat = 0.2
var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing =        4
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1
    paragraphStyle.alignment =          .Right
    return paragraphStyle
    }}

extension UIDatePicker {
func stylizeView(view: UIView? = nil) {
    let style = DatePickerStyle()
    let view = view ?? self
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
            if let text = label.text {
                print("UIDatePicker :: sylizeLabel :: \(text)\n")

                let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
                let attributedStringRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)

                attributedString.addAttributes([
                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:  style.paragraphStyle,
                    NSFontAttributeName:            style.font,
                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: style.fontColor,
                    NSKernAttributeName:            style.fontKern
                    ], range: attributedStringRange)

                //label.font = style.font
                label.tintColor = style.fontColor
                label.attributedText = attributedString
            }
        } else { stylizeView(subview) }
    }
}
```

}

This function in extension is implemented on any Control Events of UIDatePicker:

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CellWithDatePicker.updateDatePickerStyle), forControlEvents: .AllEvents)
```

&

```
func updateDatePickerStyle() {
    print(":: updateDatePickerStyle")
    datePicker.stylizeView()
}
```

**Problem 1:**

When I init UIDatePicker, font of the picker is still SanFrancisco.

But when I change value in UIDatePicker the font is changed to my font

[My Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuFxE.png)

I tried to implement *datePicker.stylizeView()* or *self.stylizeView()* on every stage of UIDatePicker lifecycle, but it can only change selected line of DatePicker.

**Problem 2:**

While I rotating DatePicker after pic.2 when all label of DatePicker is set with newFont, new labels which is outside the selected line is still with old font (SanFrancisco). And when I stop rotating DatePicker all label is updated to newFont.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QOjr.gif)

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use GCD with an interval of 0.1 to call the styling function.

Example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)
{
  self.datePicker.stylizeView();ss
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way for changing the font of UIDatePickerView (until now) is swizzling:

you can change the font by an extension of UILabel! (this is not recommended but it works!)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public extension UILabel {

    @objc func setFontSwizzled(font: UIFont) {
        if self.shouldOverride() {
            self.setFontSwizzled(font: UIFont.fontWith(style: .regular, size: 14))
        } else {
            self.setFontSwizzled(font: font)
        }
    }

    private func shouldOverride() -> Bool {
        let classes = ["UIDatePicker", "UIDatePickerWeekMonthDayView", "UIDatePickerContentView"]
        var view = self.superview
        while view != nil {
            let className = NSStringFromClass(type(of: view!))
            if classes.contains(className) {
                return true
            }
            view = view!.superview
        }
        return false
    }

    private static let swizzledSetFontImplementation: Void = {
        let instance: UILabel = UILabel()
        let aClass: AnyClass! = object_getClass(instance)
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(setter: font))
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(aClass, #selector(setFontSwizzled))

        if let originalMethod = originalMethod, let swizzledMethod = swizzledMethod {
            // switch implementation..
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }()

    static func swizzleSetFont() {
        _ = self.swizzledSetFontImplementation
    }
}
```

and for changing the color you just simply call the function below:

```
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.whiteColor(), forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

if it's necessary to be re-rendered you need to call:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = .CountDownTimer
datePicker.datePickerMode = .DateAndTime //or whatever your original mode was
```